# ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts(58,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am trying to use the REDUX Pattern to build my next Angular app and for some reason I can't import the needed libraries.

> ERROR in node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts(58,58): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.
>   node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts(58,82): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>   node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts(59,52): error TS2370: A rest parameter must be of an array type.
>   node_modules/@ngrx/store/src/models.d.ts(59,73): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "ng6-proj",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^6.4.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngrx/store": "^8.6.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "~6.2.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.8.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~6.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~2.9.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall the `node_modules` directory and perform `npm i` again?

Comment: when i run the npm i                                                install npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for ttypescript@~2.3.3.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'ng6-proj'
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/Alternant/.npm/_logs/2020-01-09T11_34_27_205Z-debug.log

Answer (score 5):

There is a version miss-match, if you're on Angular 6 you should use NgRx 6.
Another way is to update Angular to v8.